# How can I return the first item in an array using a arrow function?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a challenge where I am supposed to return the first item of an array using an arrow function and I can't get it to work.

Array:

```
var names = ['Bryan', 'Jeremy', 'Joe', 'Megan', 'Ian', 'Taylor'];
```

My arrow function:

```
var first = names.filter((name) => name[0]);
```

Comment: Why filter ?when u can name[0]

Comment: That filter would return array of first characters in each name

Comment: I did this in the first place var first = (name) => name[0]; and it works but the program that I'm doing it in won't pass the test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to accomplish this is using:

```
var names = ['Bryan', 'Jeremy', 'Joe', 'Megan', 'Ian', 'Taylor'];
let first = names => names[0];
console.log(first(names));
```

Comment: This is what I did in the first place and it doesn't accept it. Runs fine in VSCode but then when I actually have to test it in this weird spec runner thing it won't accept it.

Comment: Would it be because there is a callback associated to this as well? Do I need to incorporate this some how?                                              
 first(names, firstName => {
  console.log(`The first name in names is ${firstName}`);
  return firstName;
});

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```js
var names = ['Bryan', 'Jeremy', 'Joe', 'Megan', 'Ian', 'Taylor'];
var first = () =>  names[0];
console.log(first());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.find` instead of `.filter`

```
var first = names.find((name, index) => index === 0);
```

`.filter` is often used to get values from an array with a specific condition

Comment: `name` is a string

Comment: It actually would have worked simply because first character of the name would be truthy...just looked wierd

Comment: Yeah, that's why I posted that, I tried it in the node interpreter and it gave me the correct answer so I posted it. But this edit is more correct based on the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and return `true` in the callback for the first element.

```js
var names = ['Bryan', 'Jeremy', 'Joe', 'Megan', 'Ian', 'Taylor'],
    first = names.find(_ => true);

console.log(first);
```

Answer (score 0):

An arrow function is really quite superfluous here, but this would be one possible approach:

```js
var names = ['Bryan', 'Jeremy', 'Joe', 'Megan', 'Ian', 'Taylor'];

var first = names.find((name, index) => index === 0);

console.log(first); // "Bryan"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple function like this, which accepts an array as an argument and returns the first item:

```
const firstItem = arr => arr.shift();
```

Then just pass an array to your function:

```
const first = firstItem(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below code.

```js
    var names = ['Bryan', 'Jeremy', 'Joe', 'Megan', 'Ian', 'Taylor'];
    var n = names.filter((names,i)=>names[-i])[0];
    console.log(n)
```